# How to read SYS_GUID() that is saved as a BLOB using java.util.UUID on JPA?

Tags: oracle, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm working on an existing system, and I want to populate data using sql script.
one of the columns defined on jpa as java.util.UUID. I used SYS_GUID() for generating the uuid value from the sql side.
now I'm getting exceptions from jpa while try to read from the table where the uuid was populated by sys_guid().

How should I generate uuid from sql so I will be able to read it from JPA using java.util.UUID object?

I'm using oracle DB 11g

[update]

Seems like the issue is the format of UUID and GUID, I found the following query that convert from guid to uuid:

select lower(regexp_replace(SYS_GUID(),'(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})(.{12})', '\4\3\2\1-\6\5-\8\7-\9-\10')) from dual

It works seperatly but if I try to insert it (blob column) I'm getting 01465. 00000 -  "invalid hex number"
Also tried to use: SYS.STANDARD.TO_CHAR(SYS_GUID())

Comment: What exceptions are you getting?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at jpa.Demo.persist(Demo.java:51)
 at jpa.Demo.main(Demo.java:38)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:176)
 at jpa.Demo.persist(Demo.java:60)
 at jpa.Demo.main(Demo.java:38)

Comment: That's erroring on rollback, which doesn't seem relevant to a query? Maybe you should add your code to the question.